# scopes variables and objects in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
as.controller('OvrigtCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $routeParams, $location)
{
    $scope.opt = {};

    $scope.addSupercustomerOvrigt = function()
    {
        $scope.doAddSupercustomer = true;
    }

    $scope.addS = function()
    {
        console.log($scope.opt.selectedTabell); //Shows the value
        console.log($scope.selectedTabell); //Shows undefined
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-if="doAddSupercustomer">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Namn</td><td><input class="form-control input-sm2" type="text" ng-model="selectedNamn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abonnemangstabell</td><td><input class="form-control input-sm2" type="text" ng-model="opt.selectedTabell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Har regportal</td><td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedRegportal"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fri DHCP</td><td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDhcp"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="addS()" class="btn btn-success input-sm2">Lägg till</button>
</div>
```

Why do I get an Undefined message when Im not using objects to add my scope variables into?

```
ng-model="selectedTabell"
console.log($scope.selectedTabell)
```

The code above results In an undifined message.

```
ng-model="opt.selectedTabell"
$scope.opt = {};
console.log($scope.opt.selectedTabell)
```

The code above works. I can see the value entered by the user.

So my question, why must I use an object In this case?

Comment: use $parent with each of your scope variable and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing child scope inheritance problem. `ng-if` will create a child scope inside your controller, which means, the scope bind to the input box is the child of scope bind to your controller. If you are data binding to a primitive value `selectedTabell`, the first time you update the input box, you are actually creating a new 'selectedTable1' property on the child scope.

The solution is to avoid binding to a primitive value. Instead make sure you use dot-notation by binding to an object.

Refer to Angular documentation: [Understand Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for more info

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved. (See this example
>   for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models